# Choose between two games

Tags: python

I want to ask the user for their name.

After their name is given it will be printed out in a sentence.

I want to ask user to chose between two games and I want to call the correct function in an if statement.

```
#  coding=utf-8
import time
import calendar
from random import randint


def mygame():
    """
    Guessing game!
    """
    playing = True
    num = randint(1, 100)
    guesses = 0
    print("Welcome to my Game")
    print("Would you like to play?")
    print("Yes or No")
    Yes = "Yes"
    No = "No"
    x = input()
    if x == Yes:
        print("Welcome to my game!")
        while playing:
            print("Guess a number between 1 and 100")
            guess = int(input("What is your guess?!"))
            if guess > 100 or guess < 1:
                invalid = True
                while invalid:
                    print("Invalid number guessed, Enter a new NUMBER, between 1     and 100")
                    guess = int(input("What is your guess?!"))
                    guesses += 1
                    if 100 >= guess >= 1:
                        invalid = False
                        guesses -= 1
            guesses += 1
            print(guess)
            if guess == num:
                print("You Guessed the number correctly, it only took you " + str(guesses))
                playing = False
            elif guess > num:
                print("Your guess was too high!, TRY AGAIN!")
            else:
                print("Your guess was too low, TRY AGAIN!")
    if x == No:
        print("Goodbye!")
        quit()


def calendar1():
    """
    This prints out calendar for November of 2016
    """
    cal = calendar.month(2016, 11)


print("What is your name?")
name = input()
print("Hello %s, I have two options for you today!" % name)
localTime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))  # This is formatted time!
print(localTime)
```

Comment: Hello. Please re-format this to ask a specific question. What have you tried and what is/is not working?

Comment: Im a beginner in python and programming itself! What im basically trying to do is,   Have 2 functions and lets say they both include a game, guessing game, number game whatever! I wanna ask for users input to choose between both functions! And when a choice is picked run that function if other run other function, can u email me edwincoding1001@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry, Edwin, that's not quite how StackExchange works. We're all here to help each other learn.. not code for you. Why don't you give this a try on your own, and let us know where you are getting stuck?

Comment: i did try my own code! didn't post it excuse my mistake this is like my second question on stack exchange... a negative rating wasn't necessary, i asked to email me because it easier to copy and paste what i did on my email, without been given a warning of how i inserted my code in the text! but thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried calling the function that starts the game? What happens then? Please strive to create a [mcve] when asking your questions here. You are welcome to [edit] your question to create one

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
def game1():
    # Code for first game goes here.
    pass

def game2():
    # Code for second game goes here.
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':  # This is how you usually do it.
    choice = input('Please select 1 for game1 and 2 for game2')
    if choice == '1':
        game1()
    elif choice == '2':
        game2()
    else:
        print('Please select a valid choice next time...!')
```